# Exactly check if tuple contains certain values

Tags: python, tuples

I have a homework where I have to display combinations(range(1,36), 7). I already have a little python script what is printing the following:

> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
>
> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)
>
> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9)
>
> ...

The question is how can I check and hide those rows where are numbers 10 and 20 and 30 in a same row?

I have something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

for comb in combinations(range(1,36), 7):
    #if(comb[0] or comb[1] or comb[2] or comb[3] or comb[4] or comb[5] or comb[6] == 10 or 20 or 30):
        print (comb)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use sets for that:

```
if not {10, 20, 30} <= set(comb):
    print(comb)
```

This checks whether the set `{10, 20, 30}` is a subset of `comb`, which is the same as checking whether each of the numbers `10`, `20` and `30` is present in `comb`.

Comment: hide those rows where are numbers 10 and 20 and 30 in a same row

Comment: @AerofoilKite: Good point, thanks. Needed a `not`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = set([10,20,30])
for comb in combinations(range(1,36), 7):
    if not x.issubset(set(comb)):  # generates True if any value of x is not in comb i.e, if all are not present in comb
        print (comb)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In[9]: a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 20, 30)
In[10]: set((10,20,30)) & set(a)
Out[10]: {10, 20, 30}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import combinations

excluded = set([10, 20, 30])

for comb in combinations(range(1,36), 7):
    if not excluded.issubset(set(comb)):
        print comb
```